# Jaudio tagger library returns the track length as worng

Tags: java, audio

I use [JAudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) library to get the track length of an audio file `f.getAudioHeader().getTrackLength()` I use this it returns 3.34 as length but the actual length is 5.34.

Am I wrong anywhere?

Comment: Is this measuring the length of a VBR MP3?  Does the software return correct lengths for the [MP3s available at my media page](http://pscode.org/media/#sound) (none of them are VBR)?

Answer (score 0):

Its looks at the Xing/VRBI frame header rather than each audio frame itself whihc would be much slower to calculate